# Modified Bootstrapping

Tags: r, matrix, modeling, sample, statistics-bootstrap

I'm interested in developing a modified bootstrap that samples some vector of length x, with replacement, but must meet a number of number of criteria before stopping the sampling.  I'm attempting to calculate confidence intervals for lambda of a populations growth rate, 10000 iterations, but in some groupings of individuals, say vector 13, there are very few individuals growing out of the group.  Typical bootstrapping would lead to a fair number instances where growth in this vector does not occur and hence the model falls apart.  Each vector consists of a certain number of 1's, 2's, and 3's where 1 represents staying within a group, 2 growing out of a group, and 3 death.  Here is what I have so far without the modification, it is likely not the best approach time wise, but I am new to R.

```
st13 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
#runs
n <- 10000
stage <- st13
stagestay <- vector()
stagemoved <- vector()
stagedead <- vector()
for(i in 1:n){
      index <- sample(stage, replace=T)
      stay <- ((length(index[index==1]))/(length(index)))
      moved <- ((length(index[index==2]))/(length(index)))
      stagestay <- rbind(stagestay,stay)
      stagemoved <- rbind(stagemoved,moved)
}
```

Currently, this samples
My question is then: In what way can I modify the sample function to continue sampling these numbers until the length of "index" is at least the same as st13 AND until at least 1 instance of a 2 is present in "index"?

Thanks very much,
Kristopher Hennig
Masters Student
University of Mississippi
Oxford, MS, 38677

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is this the line you want to modify: `index <- sample(stage, replace=T)`? If so, this will always produce a vector as long as `st13`. So is the real question more about what to do to make `sample()` return a vector containing 1 or more values > 1 before going on to do the computations?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
The answer from @lselzer reminded me that the requirement was for the length of the sample to be at *least* as long as `st13`. My code above just keeps sampling until it finds a bootstrap sample that contains a `2`. The code of @lselzer grows the sample, 1 new index at a time, until the sample contains a `2`. This is quite inefficient as you might have to call `sample()` many times till you get `2`. My code might repeat a long time before a `2` is returned in the sample. So can we do any better?

One way would be to sample a large sample with replacement using a single call to `sample()`. Check which are `2`s and see if there is a `2` within the first `length(st13)` entries. If there is, return those entries, if not, find the first `2` in the large sample and return all entries up to an including that one. If there are no `2`s, add on another large sample and repeat. Here is some code:

```
#runs
n <- 100 #00
stage <- st13
stagedead <- stagemoved <- stagestay <- Size <- vector()
sampSize <- 100 * (len <- length(stage)) ## sample size to try
for(i in seq_len(n)){
    ## take a large sample
    samp <- sample(stage, size = sampSize, replace = TRUE)
    ## check if there are any `2`s and which they are
    ## and if no 2s expand the sample
    while(length((twos <- which(samp == 2))) < 1) {
        samp <- c(samp, sample(stage, size = sampSize, replace = TRUE))
    }
    ## now we have a sample containing at least one 2
    ## so set index to the required set of elements
    if((min.two <- min(twos)) <= len) {
        index <- samp[seq_len(len)]
    } else {
        index <- samp[seq_len(min.two)]
    }
    stay <- length(index[index==1]) / length(index)
    moved <- length(index[index==2]) / length(index)
    stagestay[i] <- stay
    stagemoved[i] <- moved
    Size[i] <- length(index)
}
```

Here is a really degenerate vector with only a single 2 in 46 entries:

```
R> st14 <- sample(c(rep(1, 45), 2))
R> st14
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[39] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If I use the above loop on it rather than `st13`, I get the following for the minimum sample size required to get a `2` on each of the 100 runs:

```
R> Size
  [1]  65  46  46  46  75  46  46  57  46 106  46  46  46  66  46  46  46  46
 [19]  46  46  46  46  46 279  52  46  63  70  46  46  90 107  46  46  46  87
 [37] 130  46  46  46  46  46  46  60  46 167  46  46  46  71  77  46  46  84
 [55]  58  90 112  52  46  53  85  46  59 302 108  46  46  46  46  46 174  46
 [73] 165 103  46 110  46  80  46 166  46  46  46  65  46  46  46 286  71  46
 [91] 131  61  46  46 141  46  46  53  47  83
```

So it would suggest that the `sampSize` I chose (`100 * length(stage)`) is a bit of overkill here but as all the operators we are using are vectorised we probably don't incur to much penalty for the overly long initial sample size, and we certainly don't incur any extra `sample()` calls.

---

**Original:**
If I understand you correctly, the problem is that `sample()` might not return any `2` indicies at all. If so, we can continue sampling until it does using the `repeat` control flow construct.

I've altered your code accordingly, and optimised it a bit because you never grow objects in a loop like you were doing. There are other ways this could be improved, but I'll stick with the loop for now. Explanation comes below.

```
st13 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
#runs
n <- 10000
stage <- st13
stagedead <- stagemoved <- stagestay <- vector()
for(i in seq_len(n)){
    repeat {
        index <- sample(stage, replace = TRUE)
        if(any(index == 2)) {
            break
        }
    }
    stay <- length(index[index==1]) / length(index)
    moved <- length(index[index==2]) / length(index)
    stagestay[i] <- stay
    stagemoved[i] <- moved
}
```

This is the main change related to your Q:

```
    repeat {
        index <- sample(stage, replace = TRUE)
        if(any(index == 2)) {
            break
        }
    }
```

what this does is repeat the code contained in the braces until a `break` is triggered to jump us out of the `repeat` loop. So what happens is we take a bootstrap sample, then check if any of the sample contains the index `2`. If there are any `2`s then we break out and carry on with the rest of the current for loop iteration. If the sample doesn't contain any `2`s, the break is not triggered and we go round again taking another sample. This will happen until we do get a sample with a `2` in it.

Comment: @lselzer habit - there is no need here of course but I was doing somethign with `all.equal()` earlier and there you need to wrap in `isTRUE()` so I think the fingers went on auto-pilot. Will remove, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `sample` has a `size` argument which you could use to match the length of st13. The second part of your question could be solved using a `while` loop.

```
st13 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
    #runs
    n <- 10000
    stage <- st13
    stagestay <- vector()
    stagemoved <- vector()
    stagedead <- vector()
    for(i in 1:n){
          index <- sample(stage, length(stage), replace=T)
          while(!any(index == 2)) {
            index <- c(index, sample(stage, 1, replace = T))
          }
          stay <- ((length(index[index==1]))/(length(index)))
          moved <- ((length(index[index==2]))/(length(index)))
          stagestay[i] <- stay
          stagemoved[i] <- moved
    }
```

While I was writing this Gavin posted his answer which is similar to mine, but I added the size argument to be sure index has at least the lenght of st13

Comment: The `size` bit is *not* needed. `?sample` has `For ‘sample’ the default for ‘size’ is the number of items inferred from the first argument, so that ‘sample(x)’ generates a random permutation of the elements of ‘x’ (or ‘1:x’).` So we don't need to set a `size` at all, it is inferred from the length of `stage`.

Comment: @Gavin Yes, but the OP said index should be AT LEAST the `length(st13)` and that he wanted to know how to continue sampling until a `2` was found. So I infered that index can be larger than `st13` but not smaller. And now I read more carefully your code and I see that it replaces index in each repeat loop, so `length(index) == length(st13)` every time.

Comment: This is correct.  Index can be larger than length(st13), and in necessary in these instances when a two does not appear, as scrapping a sample and reshuffling until I receive a 2 will overinflate the value I am calculating.  Appreciate the help and comments.  Very helpful.

Comment: @lselzer Yes, I had forgotten that when I wrote the comment, hence I deleted it. I've just added an update to my code that shows a kind of hybrid approach whereby we take a larger sample than required *and* only extend it we get no `2`s. That should be far more efficient than extending by 1 unit each time as you could incur many calls to `sample()` until you get a `2`.

Comment: @user687814 That does not happen in my code - I just throw away the sample and keep doing it until we get one that includes a 2. For the vector you showed, we nearly always get a 2, but for cases with fewer 2's the code might loop for a while until it finds a 2. See my updated answer for code that does something similar to @lselzer's but without the cost of potentially many calls to `sample()` to extend the sample size.

Comment: @lselzer - my last comment back to you should also have included a "sorry". :-)